# How to pass URL parameter into a PHP file?

Tags: php, url, get, router, url-parameters

everyone.
I have created very basic router in PHP and now I am stuck.
The user can navigate to different URLs and pass parameters that can be used to display data for example to get data from an array.

However I am stuck, I do not know how to pass these url parameters so they can be used inside a file.

For example this route

```
"/user/:id" -> If user navigates to /user/1 -> This executes a callback function and he receives data from an array.
```

However when the url doesn't have callback function but has a name of a file, the router will load a file, for example the user page.

```
Router::get("/user/:username", "user.php");
```

So my question is How can I get the "username" from the route and pass it into the user.php file ?

I have tried using $_GET['username'], however that doesn't work as the url doesn't have ? inside of it.

This is my code

```
<?php

class Router{

    public static $routes = [];

    public static function get($route, $callback){
        self::$routes[] = [
            'route' => $route,
            'callback' => $callback,
            'method' => 'GET'
        ];

       
    }

    public static function resolve(){
        $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        $methodMatch = false;
        $routeMatch = false;

        foreach(self::$routes as $route){

            // convert urls like '/users/:uid/posts/:pid' to regular expression
            $pattern = "@^" . preg_replace('/\\\:[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+/', '([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)', preg_quote($route['route'])) . "$@D";
            $matches = Array();


            // check if the current request matches the expression
            if(preg_match($pattern, $path, $matches) && $httpMethod === $route['method']) {
                $routeMatch = true;
                // remove the first match
                array_shift($matches);
                // call the callback with the matched positions as params

                if(is_callable($route['callback'])){
                    call_user_func_array($route['callback'], $matches);
                }else{
                    self::render($route['callback']);
                }

            }

        }

        if(!$routeMatch){
            self::notFound();

        }

        
      
    }

    public static function render($file, $viewsFolder='./views/'){
        include($viewsFolder . $file);

    }

    public static function notFound(){
        http_response_code(400);
        include('./views/404.php');
        exit();
    }
}

Router::get("/", "home.php");
Router::get("/user/:id", function($val1) {
    $data = array(
        "Nicole",
        "Sarah",
        "Jinx",
        "Sarai"
    );

    echo $data[$val1] ?? "No data";
});
Router::get("/user/:username", "user.php");
Router::get("/user/profile/:id", "admin.php");
Router::resolve();
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

You could pass $matches to the render() method as second optional parameter, and that's it. As well as these variables are accessible in the method scope, they are accessible in all the files included/required from this scope. I.e.:

```
self::render($route['callback'], $matches);
```

and in the included file:

```
print_r($matches);
```

UPD: In order to IDE not highlighting "unknown" variable, you can add a phpdoc-block somewhere in the included file, like this:

```
/** @var array $matches */
```